# appending a div to a classname using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('.wrapper');

for(var i =0; i < 10; i++){  //create grid of buttons

    var num = document.createElement("div");
    var node = document.createTextNode(i);
    num.appendChild(node);
    wrapper.appendChild(num);
    num.className = "number";

}
```

It throws an error that wrapper is not defined, it only worked when I used document.body instead of wrapper, but I want to append them divs to the wrapper div
any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there only one element with class `wrapper`? If so, replace `getElementsByClassName` with `querySelector` ([`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector))

Comment: it is the only element with that class in the whole document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
```

instead of

```
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('.wrapper');
```

EDIT:

```
var addButtons = function() {
 var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0];
var num, node;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    console.info("Button"+i);
    num = document.createElement("div");
    num.className = "number";
    node = document.createTextNode(i);
    num.appendChild(node);

    wrapper.appendChild(num);

  }
}

addButtons();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tonysamperi/7jzdsk08/

Comment: it throws another error 

TypeError: wrapper.appendChild is not a function

Comment: That's because wrapper is null. I'll add a fiddle to the answer. Wait a sec.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) will always return a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (<- hint) hence `wrapper` won't ever be `null`...

Comment: Yes you're right, you missed a "[0]" after the "wrapper" selector